# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'kast' of undefined

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-plugins, live-streaming

I am trying to put a live stream file to my wordpress 'On Air 2' theme and I have included kast JQuery library, before inserting library error was uncaught reference.... now after adding it it has changed to "TypeError". I need some serious help. My error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'kast' of undefined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):83)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.viastreaming.com/h5p/src/vp.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://www.viastreaming.com/h5p/src/vp.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$.kast({
        host: "s7.viastreaming.net",
        port: 9140,
        version: 1,
        container: "#new_player",
 onPause: function (audio) { audio.load() }
    })
});
</script>
<div align="center" id="new_player"></div>
```

Any help would be appreciated, it has been 2 days now.

Comment: It works in the snippet in your question, doesn't it?

Comment: yes it does here and when i simply create .html file it works there too. it is showing error when i add it in wordpress "On Air 2" Theme

Comment: http://www.radiomalibu.net/ go to this link and see console error. May be you find what i am facing here